# SFMC Custom Activity using Azure Functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity, azure

**Can SFMC understand Azure Function Configuration Data similar to Web app Config Data?**

I tried below:

1. Created a basic Azure Function which loads the Index.html File using fs.readFile module.
2. Optionally Proxied the Url with Default Routing. My Endpoint Url is (https://myFunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/). This works in Browser.

File Structure in Azure Function:

[image]

**Problem:**
When I configured this in SFMC, the Journey Builder console throws error "GET https://myFunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/config.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

***How the Config.js path will be identified by SFMC?***

Config.JS

[image]

Package.JSON

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The config.js path should be accesible from MC in the path you set in your custom activity configuration. For testing purposes you can set it publicly available so you are sure that MC will have access too.

Comment: The files are publicly accessible as of now. When I use Config.js instead of Config.json, the dependecies like module/exports are not defined. And hence Im getting error as unable to resolve config.js. Not sure how requireJS will bind the dependent modules.

Comment: Also I went through the code of Marketing Cloud Iframe custom.js which looks for config.json first and fallback to check for config.js.